# Use Javascript in Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I just started to learn javascript and want to use it in Rails. The javascript code is very simple, mainly for experiment:

```
var pageAlert = function(){
            alert("This is working");}
$('#refresh-button').on('click',pageAlert);
```

I must put the code in "application.js" file and inside the function

```
 $(document).ready(function(){...});
```

Otherwise, it won't work. For example, if I put it in "custom.js" or in "application.js" but outside the document.ready function, not working. I assume I don't have to put everything inside the document.ready function. I know the concept of asset pipeline, and in the "application.js", I have the default

```
 //= require_tree .
```

This should be easy, but I just can't figure it out. Any suggestion or tutorial on this? Thanks.

Comment: The `var pageAlert..` part can be outside the `$(document).ready...` block, but the `$('#refresh-button').on..` part should be within the `$(document).ready...` as you want to make sure the element with id `refresh-button` exists in the DOM before that JavaScript runs.

Comment: Yes, but I assume if I don't put it inside the document.ready, it also should run when I click the button. Am I right?

Comment: When the JS engine in the browser encounters the statement `$('#refresh-button').on..` it searches for an element in the DOM with that ID and assigns the event handler to that element. If the DOM is still loading, and it doesn't find that element, then no event handler is assigned, and the click doesn't fire.

Comment: @mccannf That makes sense. So the "assignment" process only happens once?

Comment: Correct - JQuery does *not* go back and check if the element is loaded later and then assign the event. That is why any JavaScript that deals with DOM elements should be initiated from a `$(document).ready` block or from some other event that is fired after the DOM is loaded.

Comment: @mccannf Thanks for your comments and I really appreciate. Helps me understand what happened under the hood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put code like function declarations and basic javascript outside `$(document).ready(function(){...});` block. Try for example to just write `alert("Hello world")`.

However `$(document).ready(function(){...});` will first be triggered when the DOM is loaded, ie. when your browser have downloaded the HTML and are ready to render the page. If you call javascript functions that manipulate the DOM like `$('#refresh-button')` outside of the `ready` block, will the code be runned before the DOM is ready, and will most likely not work because, like in this example, there is no element with the id `refresh-button` yet.

Hope this answers your question, otherwise feel free to ask for more information.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. So basically, if the javascript code is about the event handler(like my case), I must put it inside the document.ready's block.

Comment: Exactly! Everything that is based on, or manipulates, HTML elements in any way, have to be inside the `ready` block.